# How to ping a computer in another subnet?

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have two routers, Router A at `192.168.178.1` and Router B which is connected to Router A and has the address `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.178.21` in the network of Router A.

Now my computer is connected to Router A and my target device is connected to Router B with address `192.168.0.105`.

In Router A, I configured a rule with network `192.168.0.0`, subnet mask `255.255.255.0` and gateway `192.168.178.21`. Is this correct?

I can't ping the target device from my computer:

```
ping 192.168.0.105
PING 192.168.0.105 (192.168.0.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.178.1: icmp_seq=250 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.178.21)
```

(The second line shows up after a minute or so and repeats every minute)

Do I need to configure anything in Router B? How can I debug this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my setup is correct and I only needed to disable the SPI firewall feature of Router B.